# Send emails with Powershell mailto with formated text

Tags: powershell, gmail, mailto, text-formatting, start-process

My current script creates (after an account modification) a .ps1 file that is send to another computer and there it is executed opening a new Gmail tab with some information hosted in several variables. I need this email to have format like bold, hyper-link, etc.
Im using the start-process 'mailto' for this but i can not find the way to give this email a format (believe me, i have tried), is this even possible?

I appreciate any insights on this.

My current script creates (after an account modification) a .ps1 file that is send to another computer and there it is executed opening a new Gmail tab with some information hosted in several variables. I need this email to have format like bold, hyper-link, etc.
Im using the start-process 'mailto' for this but i can not find the way to give this email a format (believe me, i have tried), is this even possible?

Additional information:

Code:

```
$outPut = 'Start-Process'
$outPut+= '"mailto:'+$userMail+"?Subject=Password Reset"+"&Body=Hi,     your password is $Password"
$outPut+= '";'
$mailFile = "Path" + $user.SAM + ".ps1"
$outPut | Out-File $mailFile
```

So, this takes the information this way and stored it in a ps1 file, then executed, opening a new Gmail tab with proper data.
I need that some words has format, bold for the password or hyper-link for guideness link...
Regards!

Comment: please, show what you have tried ... and how it failed to do what you need. ///// the 1st thing i would look into would be `ConvertTo-Html`,

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any indication of what you are doing.  But the way to send emails via PowerShell is with the `Send-MailMessage` [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7).  If you are using `Send-MailMessage` and formatting the body of the message with HTML, you just need to make sure you are using the `-BodyAsHtml` argument.

Here's an example:

```
$html = "<body><h1>Heading</h1><p>paragraph.</p></body>"

Send-MailMessage -To "bob@fake.com" -From "me@fake.com" -Subject "Test" -Body $html -BodyAsHtml
```